# How to insert new elements into an ssrs rdl object using c# and the rdl object model

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on creating an rdl programmatically using the Object model that I have generated from the rdl schema. I start by loading an existing rdl template that contains a header footer and body as well as a datasource and dataset section into a file stream.

```
string docpath = "RDLTemplates/TemplateLetter.rdl";
Report myReport = null;

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(docpath, FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
    myReport = (Report)serializer.Deserialize(fs);

}
return myReport;
```

I then pass this to an `InsertTablix()` method where I navigate through the stream to locate the body section

```
 public Report InsertTablix(Report report, List<string> fieldnames)
        {
            int sectionindex = report.ItemsElementName.ToList().IndexOf(ItemsChoiceType118.ReportSections);
            if (sectionindex != -1)
            {
                ReportSectionsType sections = (ReportSectionsType)report.Items[sectionindex];
                if (sections.ReportSection.Length > 0)
                {  
                    int bodyIndex = sections.ReportSection[0].ItemsElementName.ToList().IndexOf(ItemsChoiceType117.Body);
                    if (bodyIndex != -1)
                    {
                        BodyType body = (BodyType)sections.ReportSection[0].Items[bodyIndex];
                        int tablixindex = body.Items.ToList().IndexOf(ItemsChoiceType80.Tablix);

                        if (tablixindex == -1)
                        {
                           //Here is where I would like to insert the tablix if it doesn't exist  


                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return report;
        }
```

Where I am stuck is how to go about creating/inserting a tablix into this the body using the object model. I realize I can use XML to create report and I have tried this approach but I wanted to try to use the ObjectModel to help adhere and validate against the report schema.

Can anyone provide some insight into how to add an element (tablix, textbox etc) into the body using this approach.

-cheeers

Answer (score 0):

I am using RDLObjectModel to do the same thing and took a little while to figure out. This is my test code (not very pretty and in VB.NET) that worked to get the tablix inserted properly. Maybe you'll find this useful.

```
'create tablix - manually
Dim tablixRFoo As New RdlObjectModel.Tablix With {.Top = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize("0.56875in"), .Width = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize("0.5in")}
tablixRFoo.Name = "tablix1"
tablixRFoo.DataSetName = dsRFoo.Name

'add tablix columns
    tablixRFoo.TablixBody.TablixColumns.Add(New RdlObjectModel.TablixColumn With {.Width = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize(2.0)})
    tablixRFoo.TablixBody.TablixColumns.Add(New RdlObjectModel.TablixColumn With {.Width = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize(2.0)})
    tablixRFoo.TablixBody.TablixColumns.Add(New RdlObjectModel.TablixColumn With {.Width = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize(2.0)})
    tablixRFoo.TablixBody.TablixColumns.Add(New RdlObjectModel.TablixColumn With {.Width = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize(2.0)})
    tablixRFoo.TablixBody.TablixColumns.Add(New RdlObjectModel.TablixColumn With {.Width = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize(2.0)})
```

...

```
Dim tColHeirarcy = New RdlObjectModel.TablixHierarchy
Dim tRowHeirarcy = New RdlObjectModel.TablixHierarchy
```

...

```
    Dim fields() = {"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"}

    'add tablix header row
    Dim tRowHeader = New RdlObjectModel.TablixRow With {.Height = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize(0.2)}
    For i As Integer = 0 To fields.Length - 1
        Dim tCell = New RdlObjectModel.TablixCell
        Dim tCellContents = New RdlObjectModel.CellContents
        Dim tTextBox As New RdlObjectModel.Textbox
        tTextBox.Name = tablixRFoo.Name & "Header" & "txt" & fields(i).ToString.Replace(" ", "")
        tTextBox.DefaultName = tTextBox.Name
        tTextBox.Paragraphs(0).TextRuns(0).Value = fields(i).ToString
        tTextBox.Paragraphs(0).TextRuns(0).Style.FontSize = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize("8pt")
        tTextBox.Paragraphs(0).TextRuns(0).Style.TextAlign = RdlObjectModel.TextAlignments.Left
        tTextBox.ZIndex = i
        tCellContents.ReportItem = tTextBox
        tCell.CellContents = tCellContents
        tRowHeader.TablixCells.Add(tCell)

        tColHeirarcy.TablixMembers.Add(New RdlObjectModel.TablixMember)
    Next
    tablixRFoo.TablixBody.TablixRows.Add(tRowHeader)

    'add tablix data rows
    Dim tRow = New RdlObjectModel.TablixRow With {.Height = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize(0.2)}


    For i As Integer = 0 To fields.Length - 1
        Dim tCell = New RdlObjectModel.TablixCell
        Dim tCellContents = New RdlObjectModel.CellContents
        Dim tTextBox As New RdlObjectModel.Textbox
        tTextBox.Name = tablixRFoo.Name & "txt" & fields(i).ToString.Replace(" ", "")
        tTextBox.DefaultName = tTextBox.Name
        tTextBox.Paragraphs(0).TextRuns(0).Value = "=Fields!" & fields(i).ToString & ".Value"
        tTextBox.Paragraphs(0).TextRuns(0).Style.FontSize = New RdlObjectModel.ReportSize("8pt")
        tTextBox.Paragraphs(0).TextRuns(0).Style.TextAlign = RdlObjectModel.TextAlignments.Left
        tTextBox.ZIndex = i


        tCellContents.ReportItem = tTextBox
        tCell.CellContents = tCellContents
        tRow.TablixCells.Add(tCell)
    Next

    tablixRFoo.TablixBody.TablixRows.Add(tRow)

    Dim rMem = New RdlObjectModel.TablixMember With {.KeepTogether = True}
    Dim rMem2 = New RdlObjectModel.TablixMember With {.Group = New RdlObjectModel.Group With {.Name = "Details"}}
    tRowHeirarcy.TablixMembers.Add(rMem)

    tRowHeirarcy.TablixMembers.Add(rMem2)

    tablixRFoo.Style = New RdlObjectModel.Style With {.Border = New RdlObjectModel.Border}

    'add tablix to report
    tablixRFoo.TablixColumnHierarchy = tColHeirarcy
    tablixRFoo.TablixRowHierarchy = tRowHeirarcy

    rdlRpt.Body.ReportItems.Add(tablixRFoo)
```

Comment: How did you generate this object model? Did you create it using the xsd and schema or was this from the report builder assemblies? The reason I ask is I see a number of properties and references that are not accessible in the Object model I have generated using the xsd command. This does look promising though

Comment: This was from the report builder assemblies. I initially tried it with xsd and schema but it seemed easier (for me anyway) to use the assemblies to create the object and serialize it back to the server.

Comment: I agree unfortunately for this project I cannot use the assemblies. Thank you though for the reply